# Issues with MySQL transactions and variables

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, if-statement, transactions

I'm trying to set up a process where my team can do some routine DB changes using variables and a basic script. I'm only on the first of many operations and can't even get it to execute. The idea is you assign the variables at the top of the script and say if you want to run the script in `test` or `prod` mode.

`test` should just mock the changes, show you what would've happened and roll the transaction back while `prod` will actually commit the transaction and show you the updated rows.

When I run these lines individually they work, but altogether it keeps saying syntax error. I would love help debugging this but also if anyone has a better solution to this problem I'm wide open to hearing it.

Ok here's the starting code, thanks in advance!

```
#ADD A NEW QUESTION CATEGORY
SET @new_category_name = 'NEW CATEGORY NAME HERE';
SET @prod_or_test = 'PROD';

START TRANSACTION;
#SET IT'S SORT_ORDER TO BE AT THE END OF THE LIST
SET @last_sort_order = ((SELECT MAX(`sort_order`) FROM question_categories)+1);

#INSERT THE NEW ROW
INSERT INTO question_categories (name, sort_order) VALUES (@new_category_name, @last_sort_order);
IF (@prod_or_test = 'PROD') THEN
  COMMIT;
  SELECT * FROM question_categories WHERE name = @new_category_name;
ELSE
  ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

Updated to include the error messages:

```
[ERROR in query 6] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (@prod_or_test = 'PROD') THEN
  COMMIT' at line 1
[ERROR in query 8] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE
  ROLLBACK' at line 1
[ERROR in query 9] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
```

Comment: can you please post the error message thanks

Comment: ah good call, I updated the post - thank you @maSTAShuFu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF`, `THEN`, `ELSE` and `END IF` are not valid SQL statements, outside of the context of a MySQL *stored program*. For example a PROCEDURE or a TRIGGER definition.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

The `IF` statement can be used in stored programs, but it can't be used as a standalone SQL statement.

Also, the `IF` statement shouldn't be confused with the `IF()` function, which can be used in the context of a statement such as a `SELECT` or `UPDATE`, which are valid SQL statements.

```
  SELECT t.foo, IF(t.foo='bar',41,NULL) AS bar, ...
```

Some statements include the `IF` keyword as part of their syntax, for example:

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
```

Note that in this example, the `IF` keyword is part of a `DROP` statement; it's not a separate statement.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> "*the end goal was to have one script ... but ... it's looking like I actually am trying to have some stored procedures that can be called via this script.*"

The original answer (above) was addressing the usage of the `IF` statement outside of a MySQL stored program. If you need to use the `IF` statement, then that could be done in a PROCEDURE.

However, an `IF` statement isn't strictly required. You could accomplish nearly the same thing using `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE` and `DEALLOCATE PREPARE` statements to execute dynamically created SQL.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

For example, we could perform a conditional test on a user defined variable in an `IF()` function in a `SELECT` statement, and conditionally return a SQL text to execute. In this case, either a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` statement.

I think something like this would work:

```
 -- add a new question category
 SET @new_category_name := 'NEW CATEGORY NAME HERE';
 SET @prod_or_test := 'PROD';

 START TRANSACTION;

 -- set it's sort_order to be at the end of the list
 SELECT IFNULL(MAX(`sort_order`)+1,1) 
   FROM question_categories
   INTO @last_sort_order 
 ;

 -- insert the new row
 INSERT INTO question_categories (name, sort_order)
 VALUES (@new_category_name, @last_sort_order)
 ;

 -- conditionally execute a COMMIT or ROLLBACK
 SELECT IF(@prod_or_test='PROD','COMMIT','ROLLBACK') INTO @sql;
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

 SELECT *
   FROM question_categories
  WHERE @prod_or_test = 'PROD'
    AND name = @new_category_name ;
```

Comment: true that. by the looks of things he's doing a procedure

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: It doesn't look like a MySQL stored program to me. OP says "assign variables at top of script", and shows SET statements assigning values to user-defined variables. We wouldn't expect those SET statements in the body of a stored procedure, if the user is expected to set a variable to "test" or "prod" to control execution flow. If this was a procedure, those values could be supplied as parameters. I took the example code to be asking about a "script", not a MySQL stored program.

Comment: i think he's just building the logic for a start

Comment: Well the end goal was to have one script I could run that would execute certain transactions based on the variables that were set but after reading through these responses it's looking like I actually am trying to have some stored procedures that can be called via this script.

Comment: @EvanLemmons: The PREPARE, EXECUTE and DEALLOCATE PREPARE statements can be used to dynamically execute the COMMIT or ROLLBACK statements, without requiring a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

issue is with the brackets

```
IF (@prod_or_test = 'PROD') THEN
```

to

```
IF @prod_or_test = 'PROD' THEN
```

syntax

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: `search_condition` is any logical expression. They are used for establishing precedence, and not necessary here, but they're quite valid if used when not needed.  `IF 1 > 2 THEN...` id identical to `IF (1 > 2) THEN...` or `IF ( (1 > 2) ) THEN...`, etc.  This isn't the problem.

Comment: Okay, so what would be your solution?

Comment: The parens around the condition are not the issue. The parens aren't required, but they are allowed. In this case, adding/removing the parens around the condition doesn't really change anything.